# Helm charts, how to upgrade mongodb replicaset version

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, mongodb-replica-set

I know the chart is old, as we are still a bit behind with our Mongodb upgrade. On the high level I would like to know should the upgrade be possible like this even with the newer charts? I'm trying to upgrade my mongodb from `4.x` to `5.x`.

0. Download chart:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/mongodb-9.3.1.tgz
```

1. Install mongodb as replicaset with 3 instances

```
helm install mongodb mongodb-9.3.1.tgz \
                        --version 9.3.1 \
                        --namespace namespace \
                        --set architecture=replicaset \
```

2. Try to upgrade with updated image tag

```
helm upgrade --debug mongodb mongodb-9.3.1.tgz \
                        --version 9.3.1 \
                        --namespace namespace \
                        --set image.tag=5.0.15-debian-11-r4 \
                        --set architecture=replicaset \
```

3. Check with `helm list -A`, and see the new helm chart is deployed (wrong tag here!):

```
mongodb   namespace  2   "Today"   +0000 UTC   deployed   mongodb-9.3.1   4.4.1
```

And: `helm status mongodb -n namespace`:

```
LAST DEPLOYED: "Today"
NAMESPACE: flux-prod
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 2
```

4. Check the version in mongo pod, mongodb : `db.version() ->4.4.1`
5. Nothing special in the pod logs, or events.

Should I be able to update/upgrade mongodb replica-set like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes This upgrade was totally possible. The issue I had, was that one replica was not running. And that caused the issue with the update. This was not visible in the logs etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).